# OpenWrt: LuCI: customize the graphical user interface 'GUI' Menu

Tags: lua, openwrt

I add new user in my openwrt system named 'user' with rpcd config.
I would like to keep the whole menu view for the 'root' user and for the user 'user' should not view all the menu, only some menu items will be available for user 'user'
example the the user 'user' will view only the menu Status System Network and Logout

[image]

how to do that with Lua script
I attached the file dispatcher.lua which uses the function dispatch() to handle the request

```
function dispatch(request)
    --context._disable_memtrace = require "luci.debug".trap_memtrace("l")
    local ctx = context

    local auth, cors, suid, sgid
    local menu = menu_json()
    local page, lookup_ctx = resolve_page(menu, request)
    local action = (page and type(page.action) == "table") and page.action or {}

    local tpl = init_template_engine(ctx)

    ctx.args = lookup_ctx.request_args
    ctx.path = lookup_ctx.path
    ctx.dispatched = page

    ctx.requestpath = ctx.requestpath or lookup_ctx.request_path
    ctx.requestargs = ctx.requestargs or lookup_ctx.request_args
    ctx.requested = ctx.requested or page

    if type(lookup_ctx.auth) == "table" and next(lookup_ctx.auth) then
        local sid, sdat, sacl = is_authenticated(lookup_ctx.auth)

        if not (sid and sdat and sacl) and lookup_ctx.auth.login then
            local user = http.getenv("HTTP_AUTH_USER")
            local pass = http.getenv("HTTP_AUTH_PASS")

            if user == nil and pass == nil then
                user = http.formvalue("luci_username")
                pass = http.formvalue("luci_password")
            end

            if user and pass then
                sid, sdat, sacl = session_setup(user, pass)
            end

            if not sid then
                context.path = {}

                http.status(403, "Forbidden")
                http.header("X-LuCI-Login-Required", "yes")

                local scope = { duser = "root", fuser = user }
                local ok, res = util.copcall(tpl.render_string, [[<% include("themes/" .. theme .. "/sysauth") %>]], scope)
                if ok then
                    return res
                end
                return tpl.render("sysauth", scope)
            end

            http.header("Set-Cookie", 'sysauth_%s=%s; path=%s; SameSite=Strict; HttpOnly%s' %{
                http.getenv("HTTPS") == "on" and "https" or "http",
                sid, build_url(), http.getenv("HTTPS") == "on" and "; secure" or ""
            })

            http.redirect(build_url(unpack(ctx.requestpath)))
            return
        end

        if not sid or not sdat or not sacl then
            http.status(403, "Forbidden")
            http.header("X-LuCI-Login-Required", "yes")
            return
        end

        ctx.authsession = sid
        ctx.authtoken = sdat.token
        ctx.authuser = sdat.username
        ctx.authacl = sacl
    end

    if #lookup_ctx.acls > 0 then
        local perm = check_acl_depends(lookup_ctx.acls, ctx.authacl and ctx.authacl["access-group"])
        if perm == nil then
            http.status(403, "Forbidden")
            return
        end

        if page then
            page.readonly = not perm
        end
    end

    if action.type == "arcombine" then
        action = (#lookup_ctx.request_args > 0) and action.targets[2] or action.targets[1]
    end

    if lookup_ctx.cors and http.getenv("REQUEST_METHOD") == "OPTIONS" then
        luci.http.status(200, "OK")
        luci.http.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", http.getenv("HTTP_ORIGIN") or "*")
        luci.http.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
        return
    end

    if require_post_security(action) then
        if not test_post_security() then
            return
        end
    end

    if lookup_ctx.sgid then
        sys.process.setgroup(lookup_ctx.sgid)
    end

    if lookup_ctx.suid then
        sys.process.setuser(lookup_ctx.suid)
    end

    if action.type == "view" then
        tpl.render("view", { view = action.path })

    elseif action.type == "call" then
        local ok, mod = util.copcall(require, action.module)
        if not ok then
            error500(mod)
            return
        end

        local func = mod[action["function"]]

        assert(func ~= nil,
               'Cannot resolve function "' .. action["function"] .. '". Is it misspelled or local?')

        assert(type(func) == "function",
               'The symbol "' .. action["function"] .. '" does not refer to a function but data ' ..
               'of type "' .. type(func) .. '".')

        local argv = (type(action.parameters) == "table" and #action.parameters > 0) and { unpack(action.parameters) } or {}
        for _, s in ipairs(lookup_ctx.request_args) do
            argv[#argv + 1] = s
        end

        local ok, err = util.copcall(func, unpack(argv))
        if not ok then
            error500(err)
        end

    --elseif action.type == "firstchild" then
    --  tpl.render("empty_node_placeholder", getfenv(1))

    elseif action.type == "alias" then
        local sub_request = {}
        for name in action.path:gmatch("[^/]+") do
            sub_request[#sub_request + 1] = name
        end

        for _, s in ipairs(lookup_ctx.request_args) do
            sub_request[#sub_request + 1] = s
        end

        dispatch(sub_request)

    elseif action.type == "rewrite" then
        local sub_request = { unpack(request) }
        for i = 1, action.remove do
            table.remove(sub_request, 1)
        end

        local n = 1
        for s in action.path:gmatch("[^/]+") do
            table.insert(sub_request, n, s)
            n = n + 1
        end

        for _, s in ipairs(lookup_ctx.request_args) do
            sub_request[#sub_request + 1] = s
        end

        dispatch(sub_request)

    elseif action.type == "template" then
        tpl.render(action.path, getfenv(1))

    elseif action.type == "cbi" then
        _cbi({ config = action.config, model = action.path }, unpack(lookup_ctx.request_args))

    elseif action.type == "form" then
        _form({ model = action.path }, unpack(lookup_ctx.request_args))

    else
        if not menu.children then
            error404("No root node was registered, this usually happens if no module was installed.\n" ..
                     "Install luci-mod-admin-full and retry. " ..
                     "If the module is already installed, try removing the /tmp/luci-indexcache file.")
        else
            error404("No page is registered at '/" .. xml.pcdata(table.concat(lookup_ctx.request_path, "/")) .. "'.\n" ..
                     "If this url belongs to an extension, make sure it is properly installed.\n" ..
                     "If the extension was recently installed, try removing the /tmp/luci-indexcache file.")
        end
    end
end
```